# Noah's flood actually happened. When does science prove that it happened?

Tags: science-in-society, alternate-earth

## Plot

Noah's Flood actually happened more or less as written. Suddenly appearing flood waters covered the Earth, excepting a few mountain tops, and all land animals had to wait it out on an Ark. The flood waters receded, a few generations of thousand-year-old patriarchs went by, and then History picks up where we know it with city states rising in the Mesopotamian flood plain.

## Assumptions

- The waters appeared by divine intervention.
- Due to the same divine intervention that caused the Flood, the land plants and animals from the ark were distributed over the world so that the flora and fauna of the planet are identical to what they truly were for all times since 4000 BC.
- The Flood happened around 6000 BC.
- The waters were removed as mysteriously as they appeared. The planet has the same amount of water as Earth does today.
- Shem, Ham, and Jepheth were evidently adopted, since they (and their wives) had sufficient genetic diversity to explain the wide variety of humans populating the Earth. Same goes with other animals.
- With the exception of the divine interventions described above, the laws of the universe have otherwise applied to Earth both before (i.e. formation of the planet, development of life, dinosaurs, Ice Ages, etc) and after (all written history) the Flood.

## Question

What is the first time in history that scientists could conclusively 'prove' that there had been a worldwide Flood? What would be the evidence that would lead them to this conclusion?

Comment: While I generally roll my eyes at YEC stuff, there is one article by a geologist that does make a solid attempt to reconcile the Genesis account of the Flood with the geological record. The key stone of his theory was gaps in the glacial ice in greenland, which required at least late 20th century methods to identify and quantify. I'll see if I can find it for you.

Comment: What does all of this water mass? Would it be the same mass as an equivalent amount of normal, regular water? Seems to me there would be an awful lot of water pressure at what we now call sea level. The earth's crust would be put under tremendous stress. Does it appear and disappear according to a normal 40 day (or 150 day) period? Suddenly applying and removing that much pressure would be bound to create a complete transformation of the earth's tectonic plates. Not to mention the effects on the the earth's orbit. Or does divine intervention preclude these effects?

Comment: And, of course, what do we do about the recorded history of China, which goes back much further than 8,000 years ago? There is just so much fossil record which is contradictory, and follows a contiguous timeline that does not demonstrate such a flood. Do we assume that there IS a supporting record that is different from the one we know, that the fossil record is incorrect, and that the evidence must be adjusted accordingly? Do we make up our own supporting fossil record?

Comment: And what is the temperature of this water? Does it melt the ice caps? What happens to the latent heat energy in the water? Did it come and go with the water, or did it come from and return to the non-divine earth? To be able to describe any time frame for the scientific discovery of the effects of the flood, one has to be able to determine what the effects would be, from a physics perspective.

Comment: And of course there is the minor factor of what the composition of this water is. Is it salt water, pure water, a representative sample of all water? Does the existing earthly water mix with it, then get re-distributed, or is the existing water like water to oil? Does all of the existing water stay exactly where it is, no mixing? And does the exact same water disappear that first appeared, including all constituent components, leaving nothing behind, taking nothing with it, including all radiation and residual radiation and radiation effects?

Comment: @JustinThyme I can't possibly answer all those questions, so you'll just have to use some common sense on most of them. If the geological stresses of 40 days of a few miles of water is the first thing that is detectable, then write that up as an answer. Keep in mind, the flood DID happen, so whatever its effects on the geological/fossil record would be, so they happened.

Comment: 'Common sense' and 'divine intervention' do not strike me as terms that should go together. A flood of that magnitude would have completely destroyed the earth, period, no record left. End of life, end of story.

Comment: the same time it was disproved in ours, once the science of geology got of the ground so to speak, in the 1800's. Of course the earth would be very different and science would probably never be invented, the extinction of all land plants would likely take humanity with it just from ecosystem collapse.

Comment: @JustinThyme this question isnt assuming our world. it is an alternative history question when proof would be found if a world like ours was identical up to 6000 BC happened and then because of divine intervention the rest of humanities development was relatively the same at least in terms of technology. And you are clutterring the question, and their question existing is in no way inconveniencing you or cluttering your comments whatever that means. I suggest you review the be nice policies.

Comment: It seems like the scenario's still ambiguously enough defined that you can pretty much pick your answer, then reverse-engineer an explanation for why that answer's the correct one.  So that said, what's the narrative objective?

Comment: This question is a bit of a paradox. Either the laws of nature work and there is no way there would've been a flood 4k years ago for several reasons (think linguistics alone, did the tower also happen?) or they don't work, the world magically became what it is today and science is not the tool to conclude anything

Comment: Related question: [What proof could Ragnarök leave behind?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2703/what-proof-could-ragnar%c3%b6k-leave-behind). Most answers to that question would also be applicable to this question.

Comment: You have a supernatural being create a flood and make it disappear, and you want the being to leave behind an unspecified clue(s) as evidence, and then you want to know how long it would take to find said clue(s) by a future society that would not survive the lack of food and wildlife, which would not have all fit on one boat anyway. I think this question is way too broad and I dobut any amount of clarification will fix it short of "whatever you want" or an entire book. -1. Why don't you figure out what evidence is left behind so we can tell you when people would notice the evidence.

Comment: I have started a discussion about this question on meta. https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/is-this-question-really-answerable-are-questions-involving-divine-intervention

Comment: closely related but not a duplicate: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/102787/can-the-pitch-and-speed-of-an-asteroid-cause-a-less-catastrophic-results

Comment: The near extinction of all fish and a huge mass extinction of aquatic life would be noticeable in many many ways. As would the likely extinction of humans through inbreeding.

Comment: By the way, a study by various scientists showed that Noah's flood - even with significant modification to the story in the Bible - defied the laws of physics, and could not happen. AronRa made an excellent series of videos on the impossibility of the flood, too.

Comment: supposedly it was the first time that generation had seen rain ever to.

Comment: There was a murder. Body is found, weapon is found, cctv of the events leading up to it. Several witnesses, motive, etc. Only thing missing - no powder residue on the presumed killer. Jail? ---- As many above have pointed out, the sudden appearance and disappearance of kilometers deep water would leave a host of evidence. Much of that evidence would be a dead or fundamentally changed world. If the world is magicked back to 'normal' after the event, in my above analogy everything *but* the powder residue would point to the *innocence* of the presumed killer.  Jail?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Science doesn't really "prove" anything beyond a shadow of a doubt. It does, however, find different things that confirm that same hypothesis, each one contributing to making it far more certain than it was before, without ever reaching 100%.

---

- **Myths.** We'd probably have consistent flood stories from Peru to Siberia, rather than just from the Hebrews, Babylonians, and a few other Mediterranean cultures. That would hardly be proof, but it would need explaining—and would mean that every culture is looking to prove the story, not just the Christians.
- **Classical natural philosophy.** The flood would presumably leave a massive layer of caked mud, which would be noticeable in some areas even to classical civilizations like the Greeks and the Han-dynasty Chinese. The flood wouldn't be the only explanation, but it would be a good one.
- **Geology: Late 18th century.** Some of the first evidence that the Earth must be much older than 6000 years old came from James Hutton and his successors studying undersea sedimentation and mountain erosion. In your world, they would have gotten completely different results, which showed that the Earth's surface really was around 8000 years old.

  - What would be missing is evidence that a much-older Earth was blasted by a flood 8000 years ago; it would be just as plausible that the Earth only formed a bit over 8000 years ago in the first place, if it weren't for the flood myth traditions. Geology probably couldn't add much to this until plate tectonics (validated by seafloor spreading measurements) in the 1950s.
- **Dendrochronology: early 19th century.** We'd found trees older than 6000 BC—in your world, they'd only find more and more trees that were just about as old as 6000 BC.

  - By the late 19th century, they'd have discovered ancient trees that all seemed to have died out before any of those trees sprouted.
- **Paleontology: late 19th century.** It would very quickly become obvious that there are two completely different kinds of fossil deposits—the ones that are sorted as in our world, and the ones that are flood-sorted.
- **Zoology: late 19th century.** Evolution goes back to Anaximander, but what was missing was a plausible mechanism for it: natural selection. In your world, there's a second huge question. Huxley promotes the idea that Darwin's finches prove that most speciation happened post-Flood (even though Darwin himself was not sure)—which certainly makes the Ark more manageable. But followers of Wallace argue that most species were already differentiated 8000 years ago. The answer (whichever is true in your world) would probably be strong evidence for the Flood, but we'd probably have to wait for the modern synthesis half a century later, if not even later, to find it. Until then, the evidence from biology might be too confusing to be dramatically convincing.

  - On the other hand… species are divided the same way as in our world—e.g., the only marsupials are the Australian families and the American opossums. How did that happen? We know from outside that the answer is divine intervention, but in-universe, do zoologists have a plausible explanation? If so, it would surely be based on Flood biology, and might be a good argument for the Flood, even though it's wrong (and discarded a century later).
- **Archeology: early 20th century.** I believe the first consensus for ruins over 8000 years old was in the 1930s, so it probably would be around the same time that your world first came to a consensus that the oldest ruins *aren't* that old. Plus, it should become obvious that the oldest ruins are all in Turkey, and it took centuries for civilization to spread out from there.
- **Anthropology: early 20th century.** Even your world's Australian aboriginal languages are probably as closely related to some continental language as French is to Hindi, instead of being isolated for many millennia. Ideas like Nostratic or even Proto-World wouldn't be minority hypotheses pushing on crank status, but as solidly confirmed as the Indo-European hypothesis is in our world.
- **Radioisotope dating: mid 20th century.** The 1940s would be the first serious nail in the coffin. Within a relatively short span, we were able to confirm (and correct) the dating done by dendrochronologists and archeologists, and we soon came up with other radioisotopes that did the same for geologists and paleontologists. In your world, all of the thick mud deposits are the same age, all of the ancient trees died shortly before that, all of the newer oldest trees were born shortly after that, the oldest ruins in Turkey date from shortly after that, the oldest ruins elsewhere in the world spread at a plausible rate for a neolithic expansion, the flood-style fossils are all the same age, the non-flood-style fossils are spread from 8000 years ago to millions of years ago, and so on…
- **Molecular biology: late 20th century.** A further nail in the coffin. Every land species had a bottleneck at the same time, nearly 8000 years ago. (The MRCA might not be exactly 8000 years ago—you mentioned Noah's sons all being adopted—but that's still a bottleneck of at most 3 male humans, 7 males of all kosher species, and 2 males of everything else, and the same for the females…)

---

Different scientific fields tend to resist answers that come from other fields. It's not that hard to imagine that anthropologists are still insisting there must be 9000-year-old cultures long after the mainstream geological consensus is 8000 for years, only finally bending when the linguistic or archeological evidence comes in.

And consensus usually takes a generation to shift within each field. It's not that common that some new evidence makes some popular theory just so obviously wrong that everyone abandons it.

But I think most scientists would consider the flood the most likely theory all the way back to the early days of science, and consider it one of the most solid theories around by the end of the 1940s.

---

Of course you'd still have people who don't believe, even a few with PhDs. In fact, they'd be pretty much the same people who run places like Answers in Genesis in our world.

Kelly, Darby, and Scofield in the late 19th and early 20th century would have laid the same groundwork for fundamentalist anti-science they did in our world. They certainly wouldn't accept the growing scientific consensus of a flood 8000 years ago—that's before the world was even created, according to their reading of the Bible—as any reason to change their beliefs.

And the reason people follow them today isn't because the Scofield Reference Bible is scientifically convincing, it's because they don't want to believe what science is telling them. Creation science would have different details from today, but would be effectively the same effort, with the same effect.

---

To follow an idea brought up by Matthew in the comments: Even after most scientists are convinced that the Flood happened, that doesn't at all mean they're convinced that it's evidence for divine intervention. It might not be until the late 20th century that all of the natural explanations for the Flood turn out to be untenable. As Lemaître said, arguing for the necessary of methodological naturalism among the faithful in science, once you answer a single question with "miracle", how do you ever answer anything else? Meanwhile, none of the world's religious texts are right about the facts—the Torah is off by millennia, the Gathas are off by thousands of kilometers, etc.—so why should they be accepted as explanations of the why? (And I doubt syncretism would be much more appealing than it is in our world, so that doesn't solve the problem either.)

If you want to write a philosophical story, these issues could be the centerpiece; if you don't, but you're setting it anywhere near today, science and religion in crisis is probably still a major part of the backdrop.

Comment: What kinds of pre-Flood ruins could have survived the Flood itself in some form? Would, say, those giant mass-sacrifice ziggurats (that ran God's patience quite thin) be identifiable as human buildings under the mud layer?

Comment: @Eth My guess is nothing. God wanted to destroy all that wickedness; that was the whole point of the flood, right? He told Noah he was going to destroy the human race and their earth, and he doesn't usually go in for halfway measures when he makes a promise like that. I have no idea how you'd create rains with enough force to pulverize giant ziggurats into mud without smashing the ark and killing all the people and animals on it, but then I'm not omnipotent; I assume he can pull it off.

Comment: "Of course you'd still have people who don't believe, even a few with PhDs. [...] they don't want to believe what science is telling them." ...which is exactly how YEC's feel about uniformitarians. This is an excellent point, and one that *absolutely* should be addressed in order to have a believable story. It's not about the evidence, it's about the underlying *philosophical* acceptance of a divinity. "Conclusive proof" is not possible.

Comment: @Matthew Definitely—but unless the story is actually about the science, that might be kind of thing that can best be handled as background detail to make the world feel more believable.

Answer (score 23):

## With the advent of genetic engineering

First a bit of background...

### Two of each "kind"

Young Earth Creationists concede that — no — Noah did not bring two of each **species** because it is simply not physically possible to squeeze that many animals into a ship of the dimensions given in the bible. Instead Noah brought two of each "kind", where a "kind" is a very subjective type of classification. But this is besides the point...

The point is that a lot of species gets wiped out in the flood... it is a **mass-extinction event**.

This forms the basis of the rest of the answer...

### Two common ancestors

These passages:

> Suddenly appearing flood waters covered the Earth, excepting a few mountain tops..

...and...

> Due to the same divine intervention that caused the Flood, the land plants and animals from the ark were distributed over the world so that the flora and fauna of the planet are identical to what they truly were for all times since 4000 BC.

...means that there is no geological evidence at all of the event. [None. At. All](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PunctuatedForEmphasis). The "only" thing God did was to kill off all land-based animals and all humans — except for the Ark passengers — and then nothing more.

So what can we look to instead?

Since the genetic record is our best evidence of evolution from a common ancestor, it would be that for your alternate world too. Since all the "kinds" of animals that were wiped and reset, they have become new roots of the genetic family trees. Every "kind" of animal will have a **second** [common ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_descent), and this will be very clearly shown in the genetic record.

The really striking part though is that aquatic life will **not** have two common ancestors... they will only have one. This is where the big head-scratching will take place and that can lead scientists onto the path to discover that there was a very recent "pruning" of the genetic family free.

## Odd fossil record

A secondary source of head-scratching will be the fossil record. If we assume that everything else proceeded normally, with the Big Bang 13 billion years ago, the Earth formed 4.5 billion years ago, bio-genesis, common ancestry, evolution... and then * **splash** * every living animal except two of each "kind" gets wiped, then the fossil record would look extremely strange, with lots of species that **should** be around, but that are not. And the big give-away would be that radiometric dating places the youngest individuals of each of these extinct species at exactly the same time, to within a century's precision.

Comment: I wanted to write that. +1 anyhow.

Comment: there would also likely be a massive 'die off' event visible in fossil records for land, but not sea, creatures. This would also likely be very confusing. Unless the divine intervention also whisked away all the drowned creatures. - Beat me to it by 11 seconds

Comment: @GOATNine Because of the huge increases in pressure in the oceans and lakes, there would be a huge die-off of marine life as well.

Comment: I really wonder how they did manage to bring "sexless" animals, like wasps or ants, as the description of 2 of every species is really vagua for those kind of animals grounds, or how the plants that require pollinators survived

Comment: @Ferrybig Ask that to Young Earth Creationists, bring out the popcorn and watch the the amazing contortion act that follows.

Comment: Not to be pedantic but of the 'pure' species there were 7 of each kind, not 2. So finding the common ancestors may be more difficult.

Comment: @aligiogia - not really.  Seven is still an tiny genetic bottleneck, and tracing an entire population (the entire species) back to seven common ancestors would be no more difficult than tracing it to two.

Answer (score 8):

**Molecular Biology** would be able to find that there was a *genetic 'bottle neck'*, as only 6000 years ago the members of all land-based species can be traced back to only *4-8 ancestors* which would gravely **reduce the genetic variety** observed in almost any species. The genetic differences within the species would be far smaller than between species compared to today and allow to trace back their ancestry to a very small number of individuals which would lead to the idea of a natural or supernatural catastrophe which reduced the number of members of all known species so drastically that 6000 years are not eneough to recover from such mass extinction.

As @Thorne pinted out already, marine life would be affected most drastically by mass extinction and one could wonder why hardly any life can be found in oceans, rivers and lakes while fossily dating beack to only several thousand years ago point towards a plethora of former marine species. These species would be completely removed from the genetic pool, but if genetic substance could be recovered from bone marrow, their relation to existing species and larger variation could be proven. Likely, nothing larger than **microorganisms and algae** would live in the water and these would be the only organisms *resilient enough to the mass extinction* to still have a **large genetic variety** making people wonder why higher developed species do not have it, yet used to have it in the past as fossils show.

Comment: So what you are proposing is that the world would be very different than it is today, to accommodate the changes the flood would have produced. In which case, our entire history for the last 8,000 years would be different, and so there might not even be any scientists today.

Answer (score 5):

Most marine life dies. Mass extinction event.

Suddenly all aquatic life is living in a [low salinity](https://animals.mom.me/effects-low-salinity-levels-fish-11549.html) water due to dilution. This will kill almost all fresh and salt water species.

As with all mass extinctions, you would have a layer of dead animals. What would be weird is the mix of aquatic and land species in the same area and layer and this layer is found globally.

Comment: Why does the water have to be FRESH water? But of course, if it was not pure water, it would leave residue behind. Sediment.

Comment: Well if it's salt water then just all freshwater marine life dies.......

Comment: Actually, most marine life would die just from the pressure.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. At what point in history would a layer of dead animals be detected? Wouldn't the dead animals be pretty well decomposed into soil in the 8000 years since the flood?

Comment: Doubt it. The flood would leave a layer of mud on top creating a perfect seal preserving the bodies.

Comment: I like the answer a lot, but I think if this God wouldn't have magically saved fish and so on, he would've let Noah built an aquarium as well. It would be inconsistent with the idea behind it.  Unless god hates fishes of course.

Answer (score 5):

Geological/Geochemical/Biological:

Ice core data shows annual data going back 800,000 years. A global flood covering the entire planet would be somewhat noticeable in the data. Not to mention the small issue that *ice floats*. If you say the flood covered all but a few mountain tops, let's say it was 5000 meters of water over current sea level (which would leave a lot of mountains still exposed, and a large chunk of the Tibetan Plateau). This would cause the entire Greenland ice sheet to lift and break up, and after only 8000 years it wouldn't have reformed. Pretty much all of Antarctica's ice would likewise have disappeared. Aside from the worldwide effects on climate those would cause, people would be able to calculate that the ice caps were only a few thousand years old.

Fully anchored dendrochronology goes back 12,000 years or so: on this world, it would get cut off at 8000. Moreover, it would show that *everything* only started growing 8000 years ago.

Comment: When would science make these discoveries?

Comment: Dendrochronology as a method of looking at ancient climate was proposed in the 1830s, and was firmly established by the late 19th century. As for the ice, ice core drilling to look at paleoclimate began in earnest in the 1950s. It would quickly establish none of the icecaps in the Arctic or Antarctic were over 8000 years old.

Comment: The Greenland and Antarctic ice sheets are held in position by divine intervention during the Flood.  That is, they float up on the floodwaters, but don't move horizontally.  When the waters recede, they simply settle back into place, with just a little melting around the edges.

Comment: @KeithMorrison Edit that in to your answer. This is the best so far, IMO.

Comment: @jamesqf It's 'divine intervention' all the way down, then.

Comment: @Justin Thyme: Exactly!  Once you accept that divine intervention happened once, where do you stop?

Comment: @kingledion this answer presumes that all plant life died off, but it also assumes (through continued existence of humans) that the biosphere was intact after the flood - does this mean god drowned all forests, and then magicked them back into life? (Because just reseeding them into the mudlayer would not cut it) why then would there be a dendrochronological break (and if he magicked old trees with new ringpatterns, dendrochronology would never become science...)? - as the comments on your question already stated, YOU must come up with the evidence, then we can tell you when it gets noticed...

Answer (score 3):

That's not how science works.

Science does not prove things in a sudden and definitive way. What science does is providing us models to understand things. As technology improves and the sum of all scientific knowledge increases, those models become ever more accurate.

For example, when Erastothenes first considered the curvature of the Earth, he proposed a spherical Earth model. His experiment was kinda limited, though - he only measured the curvature between two cities in Egypt. The curvature could be just local, or the Earth could be a dome, so his model was up to honest debate until Magellan circumvented the Earth some seventeen centuries later.

So is the Earth spherical, like every learned person knew to be a fact from Ery to our high school teachers? No, but Ery's model was close. Earth is a tad less curved on the poles, and the curvature varies a little in some places, and then there are tides on the larger oceans, so she's somewhat between a soccer ball that was stomped beyond shape and a very round pear.

On the other hand, sometimes the stuff of legends turns out to be true and makes it into Linnaeus's classification. Case in point: the once mythological Kraken now has a place in biology papers as *Architeuthis dux*.

---

Back to your world. If the flood happened, it would always be part of scholar knowledge as historical fact. Archeological finds, carbon 14 dating and genetic analysis (we would be able to extract some well preserved genes from dinos if they had died only 6,000 years ago) would increase the model's accuracy to the point where we could probably know the exact dates of the flood start and end with a one month margin of error.

But that would only be strengthening a model that was there before the scientific method was created. The flood would already be a scientifical fact when people start using the word science.

Comment: You're not really trying to meet the spirit of the question. What is the earliest discovery that causes the majority of the scientific community to be sure there is was a flood.

Comment: @kingledion I beg to differ. Renan has essentially said it would have been that way all along. "What is the earliest discovery..." visible evidence by Noah, Shem, Ham, and Japheth. After that, lots of people have suggested mud layers, which could be evidence for a long time, and that would "cause the majority of the scientific community to be sure" for thousands of years. There's probably others in the meantime, but I'll fast-forward to recent: the scientific community is already sure, but recent discoveries are just more icing on the cake.

Comment: @kingledion Or to put it another way: Based on evidence, there is no point in time when the scientific community is not sure of a flood. So, if you don't want this to be a good answer, you need to edit the question to insist that the people a few generations after Noah stubbornly refused to believe in what had just recently happened and that there is now a time when it wasn't accepted. But even then, the answer can be "As soon as someone digs a deep well and hits the layering evidence, they believe their grandparents' tales of great-great-great-grandpa-Noah's claims of a few generations prior"

Answer (score 3):

> What is the first time in history that scientists could conclusively 'prove' that there had been a worldwide Flood?

Given how much debate there is between uniformitarians on the one hand, who are absolutely convinced that the flood (and Biblical creation) are a load of , on the one hand, and YEC's who think uniformitarians are full of  on the other, "proof" is probably asking for a bit much. If you're going to meaningfully answer this question, I think you have to address the underlying *philosophy*. If whatever group is considered "scientists" in your story is receptive to the possibility of limited divine intervention, they probably consider the flood as "proven" already, and have for a very long time. If they axiomatically reject the possibility of "miracles", as does the current "scientific" establishment, then evidence of a *flood* won't be convincing. In this case, the only possible "proof" would be something that cannot possibly be explained as other than a divine act, and even that is dubious at best. Similarly, if for some reason, "the scientific establishment" either undergoes an internal philosophical change toward greater willingness to accept divine explanations, or externally, the "scientific" establishment (now hopefully you'll see why I've been using quotes) is *replaced* by a different group that already has such a philosophy, then you're probably looking at a situation in which the new "scientific" community asserts that the flood has been "proven" (to the extent that is possible for science; see other answers) all along. Bear in mind, however, that any such philosophical shift is unlikely to stop with *just* "the flood".

In short... my advice is to do your research and recognize that acceptance of "the flood", especially if your premise is that there is "scientific" acceptance of an event that is acknowledged as "divine" in nature, is going to cause and/or require a fundamental shift on the *philosophy* that underlies what is considered as "science", which in turn is likely to cause a radical shift in *all* "historic" sciences. Specifically, once your world "allows a divine foot in the door", it's going to be very, very hard for them to continue to accept the rest of the uniformitarian package and not switch wholesale to a YEC package. At the *very least*, the YEC's in your universe are going to be a *lot* more vocal and harder to ignore and marginalize.

Now... having said that, there's another point in your assumptions that should be addressed:

> Shem, Ham, and Jepheth were evidently adopted, since they (and their wives) had sufficient genetic diversity to explain the wide variety of humans populating the Earth. Same goes with other animals.

According to YEC's, genetic diversity is *decreasing* (entropy). Shem, Ham and Jepheth don't need to be adopted; they would have had greater genetic *potential* than modern humans. The same goes with animals. Also:

> Instead Noah brought two of each "kind", where a "kind" is a very subjective type of classification.

This is inaccurate. The definition of "kind" is essentially what we consider "species" today, except that speciation is occurring due to the aforementioned genetic degradation. Specifically, it deals with "genetic compatibility" and the ability to breed. While it may be difficult to *determine* if two modern "species" would have been the same "kind" at the time of the flood, the actual definition of "kind" is not subjective.

For example, dogs, wolves, coyotes, and so forth are all the same "kind" (and indeed are still capable of limited interbreeding). Lions and tigers are the same "kind" (they can still reproduce with each other today, although the offspring are usually not fertile). Probably there was one pair of "dogs" on the ark, one or two pairs of "cats" (great cats and lesser cats may be different "kinds"), probably only a handful of pairs of creatures that eventually became the entire assortment of ruminants, and so on. (Note: I'm not counting that "clean" animals had additional "examples" on the ark.)

Each of these would have had the genes to eventually become all of the "separate" species we know today; "genetic diversity" would not have been an issue.

Comment: Hello new answer and user, I like the answer and please take the time and explore this site+1

Comment: @Matthew Great answer; I especially like how it denies what others seem to assume here, that the current majority acceptance of no flood is somehow because it has been proven that there was no flood. One nit to pick though: I was under the impression that many (not sure how many) YEC scientists believed that the "kind" was up one level from species. Even if I'm wrong, I think it's a bit too bold to insist that a kind must be what we consider a species. I'll look into it.

Comment: The problem is that the YECs are still completely wrong in this world. They believe in a 6000-year-old world with a 4000-year-old flood, when the reality is a 4.5-billion-year-old world with an 8000-year-old flood. Where do you find people who accept divine intervention but also believe the Bible is wrong?

Comment: Well, in our world, Evangelical and "low-church" mainline Protestants who are drawn to science often reject their religion, but Catholic, Anglican, and Episcopalian scientists seem more likely to find science compatible with their faith. Does this mean science would have more Mendels and Lemaîtres? I don't know, but it's an interesting question to fill out the background of the world.

Comment: There is a general correlation between "kind" and genus (or even family), yes. I was speaking more to the assertion that "kind" is "subjective". It's well defined, and *at the time of the flood*, would have been essentially the same as what "species" is today, i.e. ability to interbreed. YEC's believe that much speciation is the result of genetic loss, e.g. at the time of the flood, lions and tigers (same "kind") would have been different *breeds* of what, per modern taxonomy, would have been the same *species* (at the time). In short, the tree has grown a level since the flood.

Comment: "Where do you find people who accept divine intervention but also believe the Bible is wrong?" Any non-Christian religion? ;-) ...but yeah, that's basically the point I was making; if you have a world in which the flood is accepted as a) real and b) an act of divinity, they'll probably accept Special Creation as well. At least, you should be prepared to justify why they don't.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of geologists tried to prove, or ended up giving fuel to the theory of the great biblical flood using science, notable ones are  Abraham Gottlob Werner (1749-1817) with his neptunism theory, and Georges Cuvier (1769-1832) with the catastrophism theory. In fact, since pre-Christian times there were those that studied fossils, and using marine animal fossils found on surface theorized that in the past a great flood had happened. The great flood myth is not something only the Christians believed, the Norse, the Chinese, the Hindu, the Greek and mainly the Mesopotamian had that believe too, so there were those seeking evidence since the birth of civilization.

The theory was discredited more or less between the mid 18th and the mid 19th centuries by counter theories to the catastrophism and neptunism, like the plutonism, **so I think that time would be appropriate for science to prove the flood myth** considering there would be no evidence against those theories.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: The floods in the other accounts are not as extensive, from what I understand.

Comment: @JustinThyme by "not as extensive" you mean in science or myth? Cristians borrowed many things from other religions and the flood myth is one of them, there are lots of reports on the myth in other religions. About science, there were some ancient fossil researchers, but yeah, other accounts were not that big, and that is why i theorized mid 18th and the mid 19th centuries with the geologists.

Comment: The biblical tale was pretty much taken right out of the Ballad of Gilgamesh. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilgamesh_flood_myth But these floods were based on the real fact that the Mesopotamian rivers DID flood on a regular basis, and the flooding was extensive, however knowledge of the world was limited to knowledge of the traveled world at the time. If flooding was 'as far as the eye could see', it might just as well be 'the world has flooded'.

Comment: @RonJohn , why it doesnt answer the question? I think i answered it, i gave the time in history that scientists could conclusively 'prove' that there had been a worldwide flood, and i gave the theories that without contradictory evidence could prove the flood. I think most of the other answers are getting the question wrong it is not to date the flood, but date the moment it could be proven.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the inability to disprove those early theories suggests that would be the time conclusive proof could be had, but you do answer the question.  I'm going to edit your quesiton to pull the last sentence into its own paragraph and bold-type the answer.

Comment: The question assumes the Biblical Flood actually happened. The commenters above are confusing themselves with reconciling actually geological history with this question's hypothetical version. This answer is quite right. In fact, it is better at answering the question than the other answers to date. Give geologists the credit they deserve. Once geologists started investigating in earnest, the evidence of a Noah's Flood would become apparent. At the very least there should be a thin layer of sediment covering the entire land surface of the planet.

Comment: @RonJohn When actually it does. Eighteenth & Nineteenth century geology would have been adequate in determining there had been a Great Flood if there had been one.

Answer (score 2):

You can never conclusively prove that any historical incident of divine intervention actually happened. Because if divine intervention could cause a historical flood, it could equally well have created the entire universe ten minutes ago along with all our memories, historical records, evidence of a flood, and so on. If divine intervention can happen, then we can’t be certain of anything.

Comment: Ignores the assumption of the question: "With the exception of the divine interventions described above, the laws of the universe have otherwise applied to Earth"

Comment: @kingledion The scientists in this world don’t know that your assumptions rule out other divine interventions. As far as they are concerned, if there have been two then there can be others.

Comment: From a *world building* perspective, I think it's important to examine the assumptions in the question. If those assumptions necessarily result in a world that isn't logical, we should point that out. A world that accepts *one* divine intervention, but refuses to countenance others, is not logical or believable.

Answer (score 2):

## Any time you like

Some ambiguously defined flood happened, and then God cleaned up in some narratively convenient way.  So, scientists can discover it whenever suits the story, or never at all.

***Note:***  I wrote up a ton of examples, but many of them ended up being about various types of extinctions, mummies, post-flood disasters, etc..  Kinda morbid, so a lot got deleted.  I figure that, if it's to be a story about God from the Bible, it should probably be more up-lifting.

#### Example: Scientists never discover the truth

God cleaned up everything and fixed all evidence.  Even if time travel is later invented, God will redirect time travelers to a fake timeline in which the flood never happened.

So, scientists never discover Noah's flood.

#### Example:  Scientists discover instantly

God directed the waters to etch the message

> God was here.

in the side of every mountain, in divinely beautiful writing.  Intense lightning bolts struck these locations so powerfully that they altered the stone itself, causing it to glow in a beautiful display.

Beneath each signature, God has written descriptions of precisely what happened in every major language mankind will use for the next 10,000 years, ensuring that everyone in the world is crystal-clear on every detail.

#### Example:  Upon alien contact

At the time of the flood, some aliens were orbiting the Earth.  They actually went down and surfed some of the waves!

Whenever you like, the aliens came down to tell humans what happened.  They recorded the whole thing in perfect detail across the entire world in their awesome 3D-recording technology, but they only tell humans whatever's narratively convenient for the humans to know.

Since aliens can come down and show humans what happened at any point in history, you can pick when it happens.

#### Example:  Never, because Earth blew up

God thought that it'd be funny to remove the flood waters with a second, identical flood – only this time the water was anti-matter.

#### Example:  Whenever they examine the salt layer

The flood waters mixed with the ocean, allowing much of the salt to rise above land.  When God removed the flood waters, the salt remained, coming down like a rain all across the Earth.

Depending on how you pick the details of what happened, this can have different sorts of effects that can lead to discovery at different times.

Or, you could have God put the salt back into the oceans, restoring their prior salinity and avoiding a salt layer on Earth, if that's better for the story.

#### Example:  Whenever scientists explain the platypus

Biologists are stumped; it seems that the [platypus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platypus) doesn't exist in the fossil record before the flood!

Turns out these cute little creatures very closely resemble a duck/beaver hybrid:
$\hspace{150px}$[image].
Upon exploring their genetic history, it looks like they were sudden created around the time of the God.

Behind the scenes, it turns out that God thought it'd be funny to create a new, cute-looking animal when teleporting the animals back after the flood, hence platypi!

The divine spark of their recent emergence helps to explain why [some platypi secretly have human-like intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_the_Platypus), as behavioral scientists discover whenever.
$\hspace{150px}$[image].
Maybe the scientist who discovers the truth is themself a platypus?

Comment: Just to note it, God's an **_extreme_** wildcard, so that's pretty much why we can say anything happened.  God could've left His fingerprints all over the place in any way He might choose to, or if He wanted to remove all evidence, He could've done that, too.  This particular scenario really doesn't have any limits.  Given that God is, well, God, it seems to follow that whatever He did was whatever He wanted to have done.

Comment: Re " it should probably be more up-lifting", have you ever actually read the Old Testament?

Comment: @ jamesqf Which version, the edited ones, the numerous translated ones, the books that were left out? Really, the Talmud in the original language is the only unedited authentic version.

Comment: @jamesqf Yup, several times, actually!  I used to go to Catholic school.  =P  Still though, even the Old Testament was a hopeful thing; it started with Genesis, which sets the tone of God-is-loving-despite-having-to-be-harsh-on-human-failings.  Overall, the Bible seems meant to be calming, offering order, guidance, and answers.  This effect is magnified when taken as part of the whole Bible, as the New Testament seems to clarify God's loving nature.

Comment: @jamesqf I guess that the story of Noah's flood is a good example of this.  In the story, God cares for humans, though is upset by their bad behavior; so, He does the flood.  Scary, right?  But the story ends with God promising to never do such a thing again.

Comment: @Nat: You must have read a different version than the one I had.  If it's not God killing off people wholesale (not just the Flood, but Sodom & Gomorrah, the Egyptians, &c), he's egging on his chosen people to massacre their neighbors, and any of their own folks who disagree with the strictures of religion.

Comment: @jamesqf Not sure how you expect that to counter Nat. God said he would spare Sodom if it had just a few good people. Murderous, savage, evil, despicable people being removed by God suggests he's not loving? Flood: "every thought of men was only evil all the time." Sodom & Gomorrah: Neighbors rally publicly to rape town visitors as if that's normal behavior. Egyptians: Enslaved an entire race and worked them to death similar to what we had in 1800s which most everyone agrees was disgusting... and you're defending them, suggesting their removal does not imply love? Sounds KKKish.

Comment: @Nat The rainbow is a nice moment, but it's immediately followed by God's holiest man passing out drunk and naked, and getting so angry at his son seeing him in that state that God cursed a third of humanity for all time to calm him down.

Comment: @Aaron So you're arguing that, instead of the Reconstruction, Johnson should have genocided all white southerners, or at least killed all their firstborn sons?

Comment: @abarnert That is the opposite of what I said, unless the you are implying by the genocide that literally every single white southerner, without exception, was literally raping, murdering, and/or otherwise extremely harshly abusing the Africans. If you want to suggest such a thing, then sure, your alternate scenario could call for southern genocide. As for killing firstborn sons, probably not, but take your pick which is worse: murdering, raping, torturing, working to death most of the Africans, or killing white, southern firstborn sons with the guarantee that Africans are free the next day?

Comment: @Aaron It's not at all the opposite of what you said; it's taking you directly at your own word. You said "Egyptians: Enslaved an entire race and worked them to death similar to what we had in 1800s which most everyone agrees was disgusting". And that their "removal" implies "love". So if the Egyptians were similar to the Southerners, and the "removal" of the Egyptians was "love", the "removal" of the Southerners would also be "love".

Comment: @Aaron Also, where does the Bible, much less history, even imply that every single Egyptian was raping, murdering, or otherwise extremely harshly abusing the Hebrews? It was one man, the Pharaoh, who did one thing, refused to let them pray, and yet all of his subjects' firstborn sons were killed. That's not "love" or "justice". And God doesn't even _claim_ that it is: he makes it very clear that he's doing this so that all the nations of the world will know to fear him.

Comment: @abarnert No, it's not taking me at my word. I was merely showing how jamesqf's examples were not supportive of their stance. I was directly referring to "(not just the Flood, but Sodom & Gomorrah, the Egyptians, &c)". Now you are trying to take the one part you think you might be able to find a crack in and remove it from its context. I hardly think one arguable point next to 2 iron-clad ones really invalidates anything I said. If you want, I'll even admit that the Egyptian part is arguable and I'll delete my previous comments and rewrite them to omit the Egyptians.

Comment: @abarnert It doesn't imply that. I implied that your previous comment required that for it to be used against me. You compared the 1800s slavery to Sodom by suggesting genocide against all southerners. If that was not what you meant or if it was an oversight on your part, you might want to clarify. Either way, the "move to chat" link has popped up, rightfully so. If you want to continue this, we should take it there and start deleting some of our comments cluttering this area up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83296/discussion-between-aaron-and-abarnert).

Comment: @Aaron: The Sodomites were murderous, savage, evil, despicable?  No, they just liked kinky sex :-)   Likewise for the Flood: "evil" seems to have meant singing, dancing, and enjoying life. How about all the children, were they evil too?  Likewise for the Egyptians: It might have been just to kill the rich folks who owned slaves, but the peasants and their children too?  (Not to mention that God was apparently perfectly OK with Israelites enslaving other folks, when they got the chance.)

Comment: @jamesqf No, the idea that the Sodomites were killed for homosexuality is a medieval invention to justify banning homosexuality. If you read the passage, it looks like what really pisses God off is violating the laws of hospitality. If you imagine it being the trigger for Liam Neeson revenge-killing them all in a movie, Sodom would seem weird and unrelatable, but you could still root for Liam's character. Egypt is a different story; there's no way you could see his character as anything but an evil psychopath (even if you leave out the boasts about hardening Pharaoh's heart, etc.).

Comment: @Aaron You had two points in your post. I responded to one of them. It's not a small piece taken out of context; it's half of your comment. And you're the one who raised 1800s slavery, by directly comparing it to Egypt, not me. If you're going to be disingenuous even when everyone can see the history, there's no point talking to you.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the first time in history that scientists could conclusively 'prove' that there had been a worldwide Flood?

Since "science" has only existed for 200ish years, it can't be any older than the early 19th century.

> What would be the evidence that would lead them to this conclusion?

A huge layer of mud would have been noticed as soon as the waters receded.  Noah and his family would would have planted their crops in it.

If the Flood were actually forgotten, then "Moderns" even in Ancient Greece would have noticed the thick layer of mud.

EDIT for clarification: The Ancient Greeks would have notice a thick layer of **dried** mud layered in the eroded sides of hills.

"Science" would confirm and date it just like they dated and confirmed the age of the K–Pg (formerly K-T) boundary.

[image]

Comment: Why would there be a mud layer? Once the waters are removed, the remaining mud will dry out pretty quickly.

Comment: @kingledion there aren't many "visually impactful" pictures of thick layers of **dried** mud in the sediment layer.  If there were, I'd have used that picture instead... :)

Comment: *"Since "science" has only existed for **200ish years**"* so Isaac Newton had nothing to do with science?

Comment: @Renan Newton was a natural philosopher.

Answer (score 1):

Assorted "experts" have given a flood date of about 2300 BC, based on Biblical dating. So, what does that mean?

Just to pick one example, where the scientists are archeologists: there's no continuity in Egyptian history. There's very little evidence of the Early Dynastic Period (3150 BCE - 2686 BCE) and most of the Old Kingdom (2686 BCE - 2181 BCE) because it's been swept away or buried in sediment (needless to say, the tombs are probably full of water-born sediment) and there's a long gap where nothing is going on in Egypt simply because there aren't enough humans on Earth to do so. And the odds that anyone still uses the Egyptian language? Probably pretty low, so you're looking at a massive cultural discontinuity.

Same thing in Mesopotamia. There's no Akkadian Empire.

And China, and India, and the Americas, and Europe, and Africa...any existing cultures are wiped out and new cultures only arise sometime after 2000 BCE that show no continuity with previous cultures but have more in common with Middle Eastern culture (because, after all, that's where the survivors came from).

Now biologists get into the act: remains from areas outside the Middle East show very different genetics from the people who were there before. Everyone after a certain date carry markers only previously found in Mesopotamia.

***EDIT***

Missed the 6000 BCE date in the question. Taking that into account, Archeological evidence is moved back, but it still shows discontinuities, albeit not as pronounced. The genetic evidence still stands, however. There is a massive discontinuity in genetics, and genetic data will show a huge bottleneck in human populations at the time.

Comment: Question states that the flood occurred 6000 BC. This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Noted, and corrected.

Comment: But the part about 'all cultures disappearing at the same time' can not be ignored. Time frame aside, that is the crucial answer. Unavoidably, we would all be speaking the same language, have the same race, unless you ALSO allow the Tower of Babble divine intervention.  But then, what OTHER divine interventions are you allowing? Or is it 'divine interventions' all the way?

Comment: @JustinThyme Language families were only discovered in the 18th century. If you think that the closely related languages would be the thing that 'proves' the flood, put an answer to that end.

Comment: The Tower of Babble myth was specifically written to clean up the bit about multiple languages and races after the flood.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel 'God, observing their city and tower, confounds their speech so that they can no longer understand each other, and scatters them around the world.' Even in the Old Testament, they observed the discontinuity over the Great Flood and reality, and so they generated even more myths to cover the irregularities.

Comment: @JustinThyme I like the "divine interventions all the way through" option. It paints a great future for mankind. Anything else are various variations of global extinction.

Answer (score 1):

Scientists may or may be able to prove the flood and a date is hard to estimate (and I will try) however the water itself is of little significance. Considering the story itself there are a few things to assume with it.

1. The water is in someway distributed so that marine life currently living does not go extinct. This is easily explained by half the Earth having salt water and the other half having fresh water so that enough room is present for members of every marine species can cram together and survive.
2. There are large geological disturbances under the water. It is described that some event along the lines of mountains being lifted and dropped onto the submerged land occurs and that the ground burst open and cracked apart. Sediment mud and other things could potentially be obscured by this. It is also feasible that dropping a mountain onto a herd of animals or a forest might accelerate the time span for fossil fuel formation. So that could be a point of observance. Depending on the story this event is set in one could also say this event is the exact moment Pangaea split (although in a much faster and more violent manner than history suggests). One might also find fossil layers that don't make sense unless a literal chunk of land fell onto another spot such as a fossil layer implying a forest became a desert that became a swamp that became a lake in under a decade. That situation would make more sense if each one got smashed onto the other in succession.
3. Man survived along with the animals.

Id say man would probably have supporting evidence in our time if it occurred but I would also say that such evidence might not be obvious as supporting a flood. one person might say a glacier carved out a mountain. Another might say a giant mass of water with the weight of a glacier carved out that mountain and then froze as it receded. These issues mean that a realistic flood "proof" may not exist in such a story. Attempting to prove a metric for measuring how fast fossil fuel samples formed and under what pressure would be helpful here. Id say it would be near proven by the end of this world's equivalent of the 21st century.